# How to distribute only changed msi package in Wix Burn?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I heard that from Wix 3.7 Burn supports self-update. But, as I know Burn self-update downloads whole bundle file(including all packages) not just changed msi packages only. Is there any way to deliver only changed msi packages?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario that you're not happy with?  Let's say your user hasn't installed anything but somehow has already downloaded an old bundle.  What do you want to happen?  Or maybe you're thinking of the case where the user has installed your bundle, and now you have some updated packages that you want to deploy?

Comment: @SeanHall Yes, I'm thinking of a kind of automatic update for updated package.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What is the desired workflow for the user?

Comment: @SeanHall I just want *Wix Burn self-update* to be able to download individual changed package, not a whole bundle. (As I know, Wix Burn self-update notifies user when new bundle is available. But, I'm not certain because I haven't used it yet.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible by design.  Rob Mensching answered a [similar question](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Adding-msi-exe-packages-outside-the-burn-chain-td7594057.html) recently on the WiX users mailing list.

> No. Burn provides a very strong security statement for the contained packages.
>
> Is there a way to bypass the security features of the Burn engine designed to prevent evil people from slipping malware into your Bundle? I certainly hope not. If you find such a bug, please do let us know.
>
> Note: there have been discussions about adding a feature called "modifiable chain" to Burn. However, the security implications are massively challenging and backwards compatibility would be ratcheted up. At this point, [it] is far more straight forward and secure to distribute an updated bundle. Since Burn is so smart about sharing packages, updates where most of the packages are already on the machine are really fast.

Comment: If a bundle is too large to deliver through the internet what could be the alternative solution to deliver only changed part of a bundle?